# ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable

Tags: angular4-httpclient

I'm working on autocomplete-search with angular 4. This search bar will get books information from Google Books API. It works fine when I input any search terms. But it causes an error if I remove the entire search term or input a space.[This is the error I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tA0Yq.png)

This is my SearchComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-search',
  templateUrl: './admin-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-search.component.css']
})
export class AdminSearchComponent implements OnInit {

    books: any[] = [];
    searchTerm$ = new Subject<string>();

    constructor (private bookService: BookService,
                 private http: HttpClient
    ) {
        this.bookService.search(this.searchTerm$)
            .subscribe(results => {
                this.books = results.items;
            });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
```

This is my SearchComponent.html

```
<div>
    <h4>Book Search</h4>
    <input #searchBox id="search-box"
           type="text"
           placeholder="Search new book"
           (keyup)="searchTerm$.next($event.target.value)"/>

    <ul *ngIf="books" class="search-result">
        <li *ngFor="let book of books">
            {{ book.volumeInfo.title }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is my BookService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Book } from './book';
import { BOOKS } from './mock-books';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

@Injectable()
export class BookService {
    private GoogleBookURL: string = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=";

    constructor (private http: HttpClient) { }


    search(terms: Observable<string>) {
        return terms.debounceTime(300)
                    .distinctUntilChanged()
                    .switchMap(term => this.searchEntries(term));
    }
    searchEntries(searchTerm: string) {
        if (searchTerm.trim()) {
            searchTerm = searchTerm.replace(/\s+/g, '+');
            let URL = this.GoogleBookURL + searchTerm;
            return this.http.get(URL);

        }
    }

}
```

Can someone help me out? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your method `searchEntries` returns value (`Observable<Response>`) only if `searchTerm.trim()` is `true` (so it must return non-empty string).

There can be situation that `searchEntries` will return `undefined` instead of `Obervable<Response>` if `trim()` returns `''` (empty string which is `false`). You can't pass `undefined` returned from `searchEntries` into `.switchMap(term => this.searchEntries(term));`.

For that case your code will look like this:
`.switchMap(term => undefined)` which is not valid construction.